# Find if server is connected to a client

Tags: sockets, socket.io

I want to give an error message if a client is trying to connect to a server which is already connected to another client. I have tried many ways but i didnt got what i exactly wanted. Any ideas on this?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking, i.e. a more detailed description would be useful. *"I have tried many ways..."* - similar it would be useful not only to claim that you've tried many things but to actually explain what you've tried and how it failed to address the problem you have. The idea of stackoverflow is to help when you are stuck with a problem and for this one needs to know what your problem is in detail and where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In your server, You need to keep track of number of clients connected, And every time new client tries to connect just check the number of clients connected, If its not 0 emit an event with error message, And disconnect a client from Server.
Here is Server code,

```
var count = 0;
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    if (count != 0) {
        socket.emit("error", "Cant Connect");
        socket.disconnect();
    }
    count++;
});
```

On client side,

```
client.on("error", function (message) {
    console.log("Error: ", message);
})
```

You can refer https://hackernoon.com/enforcing-a-single-web-socket-connection-per-user-with-node-js-socket-io-and-redis-65f9eb57f66a for more on maintaining single user on socket.io.